# AWS private static ipv4 for application load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

We have infrastructure configured:

- S3
- Lambda
- ECS (with application load balancer)

Lambda should fire http request to ecs task.

Till now we made http requests from lambda to ECS with private ipv4 of application load balancer (EC2 -> Network interfaces) and apparently we can't do it with static public ip address.

Right now, after each deployment to ECS, private ip changes.

Is it possible to assign private static ip to ecs/application load balancer?

Comment: Is your ALB public or private?

Comment: It's public right now

Comment: If its public and lambda is not in VPC, why don't you use ALB's dns address? Do you want to make everything private?

Comment: Yeah, the idea is to make everything private

Comment: And the lambda is in same vpc, sorry for not making that clear

Comment: Thus, you can't call public ALB from lambda in vpc without NAT gateway or instance. Same will be with public NLB.

Comment: But if ALB is internal, I could?

Comment: Yes, you could. lambda in VPC can call private resources in VPC. You can just use its private dns name.

Comment: You mean private dns name that goes: <ip>.internal etc? Is it static though?

Comment: Yes. It does not change.

Comment: But ours' private dns changes after every deployment to ecs. Maybe we don't have some part configured?

Comment: I don't understand. You already accepted the answer. The question is about the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Application Load Balancers do not support a static IP address.

If you want a static IP address you have 1 of 2 solutions:

- Create a Network Load Balancer, and assign a static IP address for each availability zone. Assign instances to target groups of the Network Load Balancer.
- If you need an ALB for functionality, take a look at adding the [NLB in front of the ALB](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/using-static-ip-addresses-for-application-load-balancers/). For the NLB have the target groups use the IPs of the ALB and update automatically via Lambda.